# Shapely module missing "geometry"

Tags: python

I'm trying to use shapely.geometry, but it seems to be missing in the module.

This works:

```
import shapely
```

but this fails:

```
from shapely import geometry
```

In particular, when I try to use `shapely.geometry`, it fails with message:

`AttributeError: module 'shapely' has no attribute 'geometry'`

Does anyone know why `geometry` is missing? The [manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) says it should exist (and the project I'm testing assumes it exists).

I'm using Shapely version 1.7.1, and Python 3.6.5, on Windows 10.

Comment: from https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html, I'm not sure if that's how you use shapely.geometry.  I think you're supposed to import specific classes from that.. i.e. ```from shapely.geometry import Point```.

Comment: Thanks, but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded shapely using the .whl file and issue didn't appear.

First download it from https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/#files

Then uninstall shapely with `pip uninstall shapely` and re-install with `pip install FULL_PATH_OF_WHL_FILE`

Comment: Thanks, but I when I try installing via the whl I get: `pip install "C:\Users\user\mydir\Shapely-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` I get `Shapely-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` (On Windows 10, btw)

Comment: you should use the right wheel file for your python.  iirc, cp39 is for Python 3.9.

Comment: Edited please check

Comment: Thanks ewong - just what I needed! (And @WasifHasan for the answer!)